# Calculate Bounding Box in iPhone using user's current location

Tags: iphone

I am getting user's current location in Longitude and latitude.Now I want to calculate Bounding Box of 100 miles around that Position. Bounding Box means min (Longitude, latitude ) & max(longitude, latitude).I dont have any idea how to calculate that.
Have any one faced same kind of problem?
Please give me any solution or pointer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Start here perhaps? [What is the distance between a degree of latitude and longitude?](http://geography.about.com/library/faq/blqzdistancedegree.htm) or [Length Of A Degree Of Latitude
And Longitude Calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/degreelenllavcalc.html)